# How to perform multiplication with a column generated by a CASE WHEN statement?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case-when

I created a new column using a CASE WHEN statement, and now I wanna multiply it by another existing column.

In this case, I wanna multiply product_hours by Quantity, but BigQuery can't identify the name "product_hours"... what shoudl I do?

```
SELECT
     CreatedDate AS date,
     AccountId,
     AccountName,
     ProdName AS product_name,
     Quantity,
     CASE WHEN ProdName = 'Modeling Package - 4H (One-time Fee)' THEN 4
          WHEN ProdName = 'Modeling Package - 4H (Monthly)' THEN 4
          WHEN ProdName = 'Modeling Package - 8H (Monthly)' THEN 8
          WHEN ProdName = 'Modeling Package - 12H (Monthly)' THEN 12
          END AS product_hours,
    product_hours * Quantity AS total_hours

 FROM 
    `db_clients_and_opps`
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a temp table and then use it later to multiply your derived columns -

```
with temp1 as (
SELECT
     CreatedDate AS date,
     AccountId,
     AccountName,
     ProdName AS product_name,
     Quantity,
     CASE WHEN ProdName = 'Modeling Package - 4H (One-time Fee)' THEN 4
          WHEN ProdName = 'Modeling Package - 4H (Monthly)' THEN 4
          WHEN ProdName = 'Modeling Package - 8H (Monthly)' THEN 8
          WHEN ProdName = 'Modeling Package - 12H (Monthly)' THEN 12
          END AS product_hours
 FROM 
    `db_clients_and_opps`
)

select * ,
product_hours * Quantity AS total_hours
from temp1
```

This helps you do things step by step and also keeps a track of what each temp table does.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would recommend doing this with a derived table and `join`:

```
SELECT co.CreatedDate AS date, co.AccountId, co.AccountName,
       co.ProdName AS product_name, co.Quantity,
       x.product_hours,
       (x.product_hours * co.Quantity) AS total_hours

FROM `db_clients_and_opps` co LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT 'Modeling Package - 4H (One-time Fee)' as ProdName, 4 as product_hours UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Modeling Package - 4H (Monthly)' as ProdName, 4 as product_hours UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Modeling Package - 8H (Monthly)' as ProdName, 8 as product_hours UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Modeling Package - 12H (Monthly)' as ProdName, 12 as product_hours
     ) x
     USING (prodname);
```

There is also a hint here that you should be storing products in their own reference table, where `product_hours` could be an additional column.  Then you would not need bespoke logic in the query.